# Combine Two NSMutableArray In Objective c

Tags: arrays, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have Two NSMutableArray Array I want to combine this array in to old one array.

How can i do this without any loop (for, while).

```
         NSMutableArray *oldArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
         [oldArray addObject:@"four"];
         [oldArray addObject:@"five"];
         [oldArray addObject:@"six"];

         NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
         [newArray addObject:@"one"];
         [newArray addObject:@"two"];
         [newArray addObject:@"three"];
```

After Combine I want output like this :

```
         NSLog(@"After Combine : %@",oldArray);
         //Output : one, two, three, four, five, six
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `newArray` in `oldArray`:

```
[oldArray insertObjects:newArray atIndexes:[[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, newArray.count)]]
```

Comment: Its Working Bro. Thanks @willeke

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addObjectesFromArray` to get results

```
 [oldArray addObjectsFromArray: newArray];
```

Comment: `addObjectsFromArray` adds the objects in `oldArray` to `newArray` and returns `void`.

Comment: Now the order is four, five, six, one, two, three.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
newArray = [[newArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:oldArray] mutableCopy];

for (NSString *str in newArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
```

output: `[one,two,three,four,five,six]`

wait, thats was copying into the new one.. :)

```
 oldArray = [[newArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:oldArray] mutableCopy];
```

output: `[one,two,three,four,five,six]`

hahaha, possibly with the side effect that newArray is NSArray and has same content. 
Check? Oh. `newArray` is still `[one,two,three]`.